# How to remove string before last specific symbol

Tags: r, regex

Say I have a string like this

```
"Delete:Delete:Delete:Keep"
```

How do do I clean this so that only "Keep" remains. Furthermore, how can I apply this to an entire column.

I want to keep the string after the final colon, there can be from 1 to 4 colons in a single cell

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sub(".*:(.*)", "\\1", "Delete:Delete:Delete:Keep")
# [1] "Keep"
```

and similarly for a column:

```
df$col <- sub(".*:(.*)", "\\1", df$col)
```

Here's how it works: `.*` matches everything before the last `:` because of greedy matching. Then `(.*)` captures everything after the last `:`, which is that becomes our final value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `strsplit`

```
# d is your column
d <- c("Delete:Delete:Delete:Keep","Delete:Delete:Delete:Keep","Delete:Delete:Delete:Keep")

sapply(d, function(x) tail(unlist(strsplit(x, ":")), 1), USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "Keep" "Keep" "Keep"
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively,

```
x = "Delete:Delete:Delete:Keep"

sub(".*:(?=[^:]+$)", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

or

```
sub(".*?(?=[^:]+$)", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

---

regex concepts:

lazy quantifier, positive lookahead